# How can I test reading and writing to the file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I have method like that:

```
    public async Task ProcessFileAsync(string filePath)
    {
        if (!_fileSystem.Exists(filePath))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException();
        }
        
        string? line;
        using var reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        await using var writer = new StreamWriter("output.txt");

        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
            {
                var lineResult = MyClass.SomeMethod(line);
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(lineResult);
            }
        }
    }
```

that reads a string from one file, processes it and writes it to another, how can I test this method, using xUnit?

I tried writing Moq tests for this method, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: there is no straight way to just "write a test for a specific member". Usually you even end uip writing many many tests for just a single member. You should ask yourself what you actually want to test. What are the edge-cases? What is the desired behaviour? What is the file-structure? Your question is by far too broad, we have no clue about your context and what your SuT is supposed to do.

Comment: If you just want to test that the contents of one file are processed and the result written to another you would need to supply (either passed to the method or via configuration) the path of the file to copy to. Create 2 temporary files, add some content to the first, call the method, read the contents of the destination file and check it matches the expected content.

Comment: Personally I would remove the dependency on the file system though and just deal with streams, processing the content and writing the result to the destination stream. This way the data can be processed independently of any requirement on an underlying file system.